# Problem with data persistence in localstorage

Tags: vue.js

Good evening everyone, I would like you to guide me with my following problem:

What I want to do is save the sum of numbers in the localtorage
This sum is entering an array called previous day, it enters localstorage without problem,
in fact I can add by doing the push without problems until I reload the page, then when I enter a value again my array restarts
what I want to do is that even if the browser reloads my values ​​inside the array are preserved I hope you have explained a bit and I hope I have your help thank you very much

```js
  export default {
    name: 'Form-main',
    data: () => ({ 
      uno: null,
      dos: null,
      cinco: null,
      diez: null,
      veinte: null,
      cincuenta: null,
      cien: null,
      docientos: null,
      quinientos: null,
      resultado: null,
      dialog: false,
      diaAnterior:[],
      ayer:[]
    }),



    methods:  {
      submit() {
        this.sumaMonedas()
        this.reset()
        this.guardarDiaAnterior()
        //localStorage.clear()
      },

      sumaMonedas() {
       this.resultado = this.uno + this.dos + this.cinco + this.diez + this.veinte +
       this.cincuenta + this.cien + this.docientos + this.quinientos
       this.dialog = true
      },

      guardarDiaAnterior() {
       this.diaAnterior.push(this.resultado)
       localStorage.setItem('resultado',JSON.stringify(this.diaAnterior))
       this.ayer= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resultado'))
      },

   
      reset() {
        this.uno= null
        this.dos= null
        this.cinco=null
        this.diez= null
        this.veinte= null
        this.cincuenta= null
        this.cien=null
        this.docientos= null
        this.quinientos= null
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In mounted lifecycle you should check if there’s current value already localStorage

Comment: @RussDeneychuk  I did this as you say and it does not save the data                                                             mounted() {
      let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resultado'))
      console.log(data.length)
      if(data.length > 0) {
        this.guardarDiaAnterior()
      }
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values start again at zero because you constantly start from your `this.diaAnterior` variable which, at each reload, becomes an empty array.  So, you find yourself `push` your new value into an empty array each time you reload.

You have to get the value of your localStorage, store it in `this.diaAnterior` and then `push` your result to add a new value to the old ones.

In code it would look like this:

```js
   guardarDiaAnterior() {
       const resultStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resultado'))
       if (resultStorage){
           this.diaAnterior = resultStorage
       }
       this.diaAnterior.push(this.resultado)
       localStorage.setItem('resultado',JSON.stringify(this.diaAnterior))
       this.ayer= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resultado'))
   },
```

Comment: This worked for me, I still can't rate because I'm a newbie as soon as I can I'll come rate thank you very much for the help